# Pull or backup only the contacts from Android

Tags: adb, backup, command-line

My phone is on a bootloope _ soft bricked. I have managed to detect it via adb on recovery mode. So now I want to know the exact command to pull contacts first from the phone to my pc.

1. Is this correct?

   adb backup -apk -shared -all -f C:\test.ab
2. Next what is the generic (original factory) directory for phone saving all the pictures/pdfs?
   What is the command I should run to pull those from phone to pc?
3. Is pulling faster or healthier a bricked phone than backing up into pc?
4. Also due to UK language settings my pc has no backslash, is there a way to get it into command prompt?

(Since I am nooby and I just crashed everything I know right now from last night - please have mercy. I want to make sure the commands are precise.)

Comment: 1. Is what correct? 3. I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking. 4. UK keyboards do have a backslash, next to the Z key. If you're having trouble entering text on your PC, you'll want to fix that first: we don't have the expertise to help you with that here.

Comment: You may ignore that backslash although next to 'z' there's no backslash. Anyway, I found out I haven't managed to root my soft-brick device. Can u help me on that please?